# Scatterplot do not show any graphs

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

i had a problem where i use `sns.scatterplot` but it does not show me anything, just a blank space,also I tried to use `plt.legend` but got error.  Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as  plt

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/ruslanpilipyuk/Desktop/data.csv')

sns.scatterplot(a=df['CRIM'], label= 'Criminal Level')
sns.scatterplot(a=df['LSTAT'],label= 'Poorness of area')
plt.title('Relationship between crime level and poorness of area')
plt.show()
```

Comment: isn't the signature for `sns.scatterplot` is `sns.scatterplot(x=some_data, y=some_data)`?

Comment: what is `a` argument? https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html

Answer (score 0):

Plot your picture the following way:

```
sns.scatterplot(x='CRIM', y='LSTAT', data=df)
plt.title('Relationship between crime level and poorness of area')
plt.xlabel('Criminal Level')
plt.ylabel('Poorness of area')
plt.show()
```

Important details:

- There should be a **single** call to *sns.scatterplot*.
- *data* argument passes the **whole** DataFrame.
- *x* and *y* indicate column names.
- Set axis labels in **separate** instructions (*sns.scatterplot* has no
  *label* parameter).